# Why do I get and Error (NameError name 'first' not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

```
def one():
    if(slist[0] == 'a'):
        first = 3
```

This code is on my 'numbers.py' file and I have it repeated for each letter of the alphabet. This file is imported to the main file I am launching.

```
import number
from number import *
if(len(number.string) == 1):
    number.one()

print(number.first)
```

This code is on my main file and is supposed to print a '3' if you type 'A' when it asks you what you would like to decode

Answer (score 1):

first variable is local to function one by default, it will no longer exist once exit the function, declare it as global to make it accessible outside function

And you might not need the line `from number import *` since you should be  accessing from number namespace. Its not recommended to use `import *` also to avoid namespace pollution

```
first=None
def one():
    global first
    if(slist[0] == 'a'):
        first = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

A different solution could be to return your `first` variable, so that, you could use it in your `main`as you want.

I show you:

```
def one():
    if(slist[0] == 'a'):
        first = 3
        return first
        ''' you could use this instead '''
        #return 3
```

and then, back in your main:

```
import number
if(len(number.string) == 1):
    first = number.one()

print(first)
```